# ZeroMQ use with .net core

Tags: c#, zeromq

Is it possible to use ZeroMQ (version 4.1.0.31) in a .NET core project? It seems that is targeted only for .NET framework. If I download the package from nuget and try to initialise a `ZContext` it throws an exception.

```
System.TypeInitializationException
HResult=0x80131534
Message=The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception.
Source=ZeroMQ
StackTrace:
at ZeroMQ.ZContext..ctor()
at TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 2521

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.ZSymbol' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
FieldAccessException: Cannot set initonly static field 'EPERM' after type 'ZeroMQ.ZError' is initialized.
```

Comment: There is a 100% C#-native port: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetMQ Have you tried that?

Comment: We have existing libraries implemented based on ZMQ and want to re-use them on .net core project.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Didn't find any solution. Decided not to migrate to .net core for now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the maintainer has done work to port it to .NET Standard, but has not yet released it. [See this issue](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/issues/182).

The [latest release on GitHub](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/releases) was made after the changes to support .NET Standard, so using that instead of the NuGet package should work. I was able to reference `bin/Release/ZeroMQ.dll` from a .NET Core project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to reference as you mentioned but i still cannot run. try to initiate zcontext e.g. var test = new ZContext(); (using .net core 3.0)

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception.
  Source=ZeroMQ
  StackTrace:
   at ZeroMQ.ZContext..ctor() in C:\Projects\ZeroMq.Release\ZContext.cs:line 54
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 10

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.ZSymbol' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
FieldAccessException: Cannot set initonly static field 'EPERM' after type 'ZeroMQ.ZError' is initialized.